# Microwave Oscillator: Both Ports Unstable?

Tags: oscillator, microwave

I'm just wondering, for  microwave oscillators, I think both ports need to be in the transistor's unstable region.  What would happen if just one port were in the unstable region and the other in the stable region?  Could it oscillate? I'm thinking maybe it'd try to oscillate at one port, and the other port would attenuate the oscillation and the circuit would probably just do nothing.

Update:

The image below is from *RF Circuit Design: Theory and Applications* by R. Ludwig and P. Bretchko.

Basically, what I'm asking is, what happens if \$\Gamma_{S}\$ is chosen such that it lies in the transistor's **unstable** region, whereas \$\Gamma_{L}\$ is chosen such that it lies in the transistor's **stable** region.  My understanding is that both \$\Gamma_{S}\$ and \$\Gamma_{L}\$ must be in the transistor's unstable region for this to be an oscillator.

[image: Oscillator]

Comment: Which ports do you refer to?

Comment: The ports of the transistor.  I'll post a picture.